# I have more than one face, but I have no eyes. I roll out of hand during multiple tries

Tags: riddle, rhyme, calculation-puzzle, poetry

> > **Riddle me this:**
>
> *I have more than one face, but I have no eyes.*
>
> *I roll out of hand during multiple tries.*
>
> *I very much often do not roll alone;*
>
> *I have a partner, who like myself, enjoys being thrown.*
>
> *To you, we roll; but to us, we dance.*
>
> *We are closely associated with the idea of chance.*
>
> *You cannot predict what faces we will show,*
>
> *Regardless of how much effort you put in your throw.*
>
> *Try as you wish, but there is no guarantee.*
>
> *Though perhaps you can guess exactly what I could be.*

---

I made up this riddle for fun. There is a shop that I go to every week to answer their weekly riddles, and I showed this riddle to a couple of receptionists there. They said it was pretty good, however, some of my other friends found it a bit easy — the first line gave it away, thus I changed it to what it is now in the sandbox.

And so, I share this riddle with you! Hints for the answer are below.

---

**Hint:**

> *Each of my faces have a different number.*
>  *You obtain $21$ when you add them together.*

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie thank you for the edit. I was trying to do what you just did :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you a

> Die or a single dice?

I have more than one face, but I have no eyes.

> The have six sides and when you have two you have "snake eyes" but they are not real.

I roll out of hand during multiple tries.

> You roll them.

I very much often do not roll alone;

> Most games have two die.

I have a partner, who like myself, enjoys being thrown.

> You can have a pair.

To you, we roll; but to us, we dance.

> You roll them?

We are closely associated with the idea of chance.

> There is only probability associated with what you get.

You cannot predict what faces we will show,

> But you will never know for sure.

Regardless of how much effort you put in your throw.

> It will not really help to blow on it.

Try as you wish, but there is no guarantee.

> Same as above.

Though perhaps you can guess exactly what I could be.

> Your guess may be right.

**Regarding the hints**

> Most die's have the numbers 1-6 on them and that adds up to 21.

Comment: You have the answer correct! Yes, especially on a site like this with many good riddlers, I figured this one would be pretty easy. However, I don't understand the "snake eyes" part. I have never seen dice with snake eyes.

Comment: I got that because when you roll two ones you get snake eyes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_eyes

Comment: Ahh, I see. I would probably have to construct a new verse to include that feat. Anyway, congratulations! $$(+1) \ \ \color{green}{\checkmark}$$

Comment: Nitpick: one die, two or more dice.

Comment: @shoover no it's one die because it is from its perspective :)