# I may have initials but I do not have a name. My purposes have brought myself plenty of fame

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

> > **Riddle me this:**
>
> *I may have initials, but I do not have a name.*
>
> *My purposes have brought myself plenty of fame.*
>
> *I have brothers and sisters and cousins and more.*
>
> *We make stories and pictures, written and drawn.*
>
> *Unlike yourself and animals and plants,*
>
> *We never grow but are tallest at first glance.*
>
> *Our looks vary depending on colour and height,*
>
> *But within all of us is a stick of graphite.*
>
> *Our closest friend is a sheet of paper.*
>
> *Guess what I am, and it might do you a favour.*

---

I made up this riddle for fun. Hope you enjoy!

Hints for the answer are below.

---

**Hint:**

> *I am wooden and narrow, with a point and a tip;*
>  *I am an object that nearly every student should equip.*

Comment: I ... really don't think this needed a hint.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan would you suggest I try making my riddles a little harder?

Comment: Well, for my taste they've all been extremely straightforward, more *slightly oddly worded description* than riddle. I don't want to claim that that's *bad*, but I think that for the clientele here harder would be probably better.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan ok, thank you. I will try making a harder riddle :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are a

> HB Pencil

may have initials, but I do not have a name.
My purposes have brought myself plenty of fame.

> You can write and draw, and the initials for the pencil are HB.

I have brothers and sisters and cousins and more.

> Pencil crayon, crayons, markers, and pens.

We make stories and pictures, written and drawn.

> These are all things you can do with pencils.

Unlike yourself and animals and plants,
We never grow but are tallest at first glance.

> The shorten with use and never grow.

Our looks vary depending on colour and height,
But within all of us is a stick of graphite.

> Pencils can vary, but they all still have graphite in them.

Our closest friend is a sheet of paper.

> You use a pencil on paper!

**And the hint**
I am wooden and narrow, with a point and a tip;
I am an object that nearly every student should equip.

> That is what a pencil looks like, and students use them in school.

Comment: Well Done! You got it! It was pretty easy, I must admit. The only part wrong was the "initials" section $-$ I was referring to a **HB Pencil** in particular (because it has the initials HB, representing the type of graphite the pencil has). Other than that, congratulations! $$(+1) \ \ \color{green}{\checkmark}$$ Also, I think you might have answered one of my riddles before :)

Comment: Ahh thanks and it was this question,       https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67520/i-have-more-than-one-face-but-i-have-no-eyes-i-roll-out-of-hand-during-multipl        Good puzzle :D

Comment: Also, if you wait 20-24 hours to accept an answer you may get more view(and votes)!

Comment: Ok, thank you for the suggestion. Personally, I do not really care that much about views and votes (unless I am disrespecting the site, which I will never). I just like making riddles and putting them up for others to enjoy, like yourself :)